# How do I include visual c++ redistributable in installer

Tags: c++

I've been trying to figure this out for quite a while. I want to create an installer for my app, but it requires the visual c++ redistributable. Whenever I try to install it on another computer, it says missing dlls like VCRUNTIME140_1.dll. Ideally I want to either remove the requirement for these files, or include those files with the installer.

The list of DLLs it said was missing:

VCRUNTIME140_1.dll
VCRUNTIME140D.dll
ucrtbased.dll

Comment: The correct files are here: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: `VCRUNTIME140D.dll` if this file is required it is a bug in your application. This is part of the debug runtime. It is a violation of the Visual Studio licence to redistribute debug dlls. These are only permitted to be used on machines with Visual Studio installed. You need to build your application in release mode.

Comment: What kind of bug would cause VCRUNTIME140D to be required

Comment: I added additional information

Comment: I have the redistributibles I just want to include it in the installer

Comment: The redistributable will not contain the file I already told you about.

Comment: My project is build in Release mode so I dont know why that file is being used

Comment: My guess is you are linking to a third party dll (some other library) and you are using a debug binary for release.

Comment: I mean I have the vc_redist.x64.exe

Comment: That is the correct file. I package it with all of my applications.

Comment: can vc_redist.x64.exe be merged into the installer?

Comment: Yes I merge it into my NSIS based installer on all of my projects.

Comment: Interesting. Im reading up on NSIS

Comment: That is only one way. There are many installers avaiable. I use it because of it integration with `CMake`. I use CMake to generate all of my Visual Studio projects so this is an easy choice for me.

Comment: Yeah Im thinking more of trying to include it in an installer made in visual studio

Comment: Ok I fixed VCRUNTIME140_1.dll by adding a msm, however I don't know how to find what library is running in debug mode. I have a lot of libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you're not including other files in your program, you might find it easier to statically build your project. To do so, go to `Project->Project Properties->C/C++->Code Generation` and set `Runtime Library` to `Multi-Threaded(/MT)`.